# Protobuf Inheritance hierarchy

Tags: inheritance, protocol-buffers

I have a base class defined as:

```
[ProtoInclude(100, "Module.v1.DataObject.B, Module.v1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]
[ProtoInclude(101, "Module.v2.DataObject.B, Module.v2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")]    
public class A
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name;
    }
```

Derived classes are defined in 2 different assemblies:

Module.v1 has

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class B: A
{
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int Key;
}
```

Module.v2 has

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class B: A
{
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int Key;
}
```

When I try to serialize/deserialize one of these, for eg. Module.v2.DataObject.B, protobuf throws the exception -
"A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy Module.v2.DataObject.B"

Could you please help with what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Interesting; I will have to look

Comment: "cannot repro" (see answer for full setup)

Comment: Thanks Marc! I missed out on replying earlier - so the issue was the projects had some build config mismatch addressing which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot repro; I have 3 projects:

- test rig
- first module
- second module

Both modules reference the test rig, since that defines `A`. The outputs of the two modules have then been made available as files in the location of the test rig, to be loaded.

My test rig does:

```
static void Main()
{
    var type = Type.GetType("Module.v1.DataObject.B, Module.v1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    A a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(a);
    Console.WriteLine(clone.GetType().FullName);

    type = Type.GetType("Module.v2.DataObject.B, Module.v2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    a = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    clone = Serializer.DeepClone(a);
    Console.WriteLine(clone.GetType().FullName);
}
```

which works fine, outputting:

```
Module.v1.DataObject.B
Module.v2.DataObject.B
```